# I cant find my app's apk file

Tags: java, android

I've look almost everywhere for it but I still can't find it.Its not in apps/build/outputs.Where else could it be? I've never move any android studio file.

Comment: Try re-building your project and see if the apk is generated?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild you project in Android Studio. AS stores the APK in a different folder from Eclipse.